# todonotes problem with amsbook class

Tags: table-of-contents, todonotes, amsbook

I'm trying to use todonotes with `amsbook` documentclass. I can add a todo (using `\todo{fix this}`) to part of the text and I can generate a Todo list for the table of contents using `\todototoc`, but the compilation has some problems.

From looking at the `todonotes` documentation I have seen that the package has a known conflict with `amsart` and a fix is supplied in the documentation. The fix doesn't quite work for `amsbook` and I don't know enough about what it's doing to edit it.

The problems are that whilst compiling the LaTeX I get the warning that `\todototoc` is an undefined control sequence. Ignoring the warning and continuing the compilation, I see that the `\todo` I have created is not put on the same page as the heading for the list.

A smallish working example follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{amsbook}  

 \usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref} % for links
 \usepackage{todonotes} 


  \begin{document}

  \title{A sample book in amsbook style}
   \author{me}
   \maketitle

   \tableofcontents
    \todototoc  % put an entry for the list of todos in the  table of contents

    % \listoftodos   This is the usual command for making a list of to dos

   % The following was taken from the todonotes documentation on how to resolve a problem with the amsart class.
   % It doesn't quite work for amsbook as the list entries are put on the page after the "Todo list" heading.

   \makeatletter
   \providecommand\@dotsep{5}
   \makeatother
   \listoftodos\relax


    \chapter{The test chapter}
    Some text\todo{really need some more text!}

    \end{document}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `amsbook` defines `\@starttoc` with two arguments (I don't think it was a wise decision). So you have to redefine `\listoftodos` to pass correctly what `\@starttoc` wants:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{amsbook}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref} % for links

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@dotsep{5}
\renewcommand{\listoftodos}[1][\@todonotes@todolistname]{%
  \@starttoc{tdo}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{A sample book in amsbook style}
\author{me}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\listoftodos

\chapter{The test chapter}
Some text\todo{really need some more text!}

\end{document}
```

`\todototoc` is not needed as `amsbook` takes care of it.